# Is calculating the distance between users a feature of Geocoding API?

Tags: geocoding

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to post this. I've never used this.

I am creating a mobile app. I'm not the developer. I hired one to develop my app.

We are using Google Cloud Platform, which it's free for one year. Next October will stop being free. And today we realized we would pay 156 dollars a month for just using Geocoding API (if it wasn't free). And only a very few people are using the app for testing.

We still didn't launch it. And honestly, it's too much money for us, because if too many people would start to use the app, that cost would be higher.

Now, Geocoding is the process of converting addresses into geographic coordinates, which we are using in the app. And we are also showing the distances between users, like Tinder does. We plan to remove Geocoding API, because it's not absolutely necessary to convert addresses into geographic coordinates. But we need to show the distances between users.

I want to ask: Is calculating the distance between users a feature of Geocoding API? Because if it is, we'll have to remove this feature too.

I hope I was clear with my question.

Thank you,
Juan

Answer (score 0):

If you get the users coordinates from another API, you can use the latitude and longitude to calculate the distance between two points using the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

> Haversine formula:    a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
>
> c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
>
> d = R ⋅ c
>
> where φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius
>   = 6,371km); note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!

JavaScript:

```
var R = 6371e3; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

In [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you can find a full example of this